# pyjnius import error ? issues during running kivy's example android program

Tags: python, dll, error-handling, installation, kivy

I installed kivi, pyjnius and jnius with pip using

```
python.exe -m pip install pyjnius
python.exe -m pip install jnius
```

it was succesfully built and installed.

I tried to run one of the kivy's examples:

```
'''
Compass example


This example is a demonstration of Hardware class usage.
But it has severals drawbacks, like using only the magnetic sensor, and
extrapolating values to get the orientation. The compass is absolutely not
accurate.

The right way would be to get the accelerometer + magnetic, and computer
everything according to the phone orientation. This is not the purpose of 
this
example right now.

You can compile it with::

./build.py --package org.test.compass --name compass \
    --private ~/code/kivy/examples/android/compass \
    --window --version 1.0 debug installd
'''


import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.0')

from jnius import autoclass
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.animation import Animation

Hardware = autoclass('org.renpy.android.Hardware')


class CompassApp(App):
.
.
.
```

and got the error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Janka\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-06- 
03_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) 
[MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\share\kivy- 
examples\android\compass\main.py", line 25, in <module>
 from jnius import autoclass
File "C:\Users\Janka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site- 
packages\jnius\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
 from .jnius import *  # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new in kivy, only trying to get it work on given examples. Maybe I need to compile it before running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your pyjnius is compiled properly. However, the bigger problem is that your pyjnius code will only work on Android - org.renpy.android.Hardware does not exist on the desktop.

This is usually the case with pyjnius, although it can work on the desktop there isn't much point in having it there if you only need it for Android. I would usually resolve this by conditionally importing and using pyjnius only if running on Android.

Comment: Okay, so, If I want to develop an android app, (or an app that should work on both desktop and android?) using desktop to write the code, I have to import different libraries depending on that, which hardware do I use, right? this makes sense for me. If so, could you please give me an example of code running both desktop and android (I am not sure how to write the condition)?

Comment: You can check `kivy.platform` to get the platform, and if it equals `android` then important and use your pyjnius stuff.